# Prerender io java wrong route

Tags: angularjs, google-app-engine, web-crawler, hashbang, prerender

I am having a problem with prerender.io. It works just fine if I am using node/express on localhost, but when I am trying to make it work with java (https://github.com/greengerong/prerender-java/) on google app engine it re-routes automatically.

When I write this into my browser and hit enter,
http://www.example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/browse/761238167868/

It redirects automatically to
http://www.example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/browse/761238167868#!/browse

In app.js I have the following:

```
  module.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/browse', {
      templateUrl: 'views/browse.html'
         //a lot of .when() ....
    }).otherwise({redirectTo: '/browse'});
```

I believe it is a problem with the app engine server or the middleware installation, because it works just fine with node/express.

Do I need to rewrite something to make app engine handle hashbangs (#!) or something?

Here's my web.xml:

```
 <filter>
      <filter-name>prerender</filter-name>
      <filter-class>com.github.greengerong.PreRenderSEOFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>crawlerUserAgents</param-name>
          <param-value>FacebookExternalHit</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>crawlerUserAgents</param-name>
          <param-value>facebookexternalhit</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>crawlerUserAgents</param-name>
          <param-value>facebookexternalhit/1.0</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>crawlerUserAgents</param-name>
          <param-value>facebookexternalhit/1.1</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>crawlerUserAgents</param-name>
          <param-value>Facebot</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>prerenderToken</param-name>
          <param-value>mytoken</param-value>
      </init-param>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>prerender</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Can you post your web.xml or wherever you register the java middleware after you remove any private information from it?

Comment: Posted the middleware part of my web.xml